# What exactly is a "smooth surface" in geometrical optics?

Tags: optics, differential-geometry, definition, geometric-optics

Often in elementary optics, one considers so-called "smooth surfaces" (this is to be viewed in contrast with the idea of a "rough surface"), with plane mirrors being a prototypical example of such a surface. Another example commonly given is the surface of a still body of water. But what about something less planar, for instance a "well-polished" sphere; does that count as a smooth surface? Is there some mathematically rigorous way to characterize which surfaces are "smooth" and which ones are "rough"? I'm thinking it could be defined as follows:

Definition (Smooth Surfaces): A surface $S\subseteq\textbf R^3$ is said to be smooth if and only if it has a well-defined tangent plane at every point $\textbf x\in S$.

Although I would be interested in hearing what others have to say about this :)

Comment: Generally smooth implies that it has derivatives of every order, ie the level function of that shape is $C^\infty$. Simply having a well-defined tangent plane at every point only require it to $C^1$, which is probably good enough for most theorems still.

Comment: I wasn't intending on referring to the use of the word "smooth" in that technical sense, rather I was referring to the more informal sense in which the word is often used in geometrical/ray optics. Although are you saying that the "infinitely differentiable" definition of "smooth" in math is the same meaning as "smooth" in geometrical optics?

Answer (score 2):

Optical surfaces are often rated on their "[Scratch and Dig](https://www.edmundoptics.com/knowledge-center/application-notes/lasers/understanding-surface-quality-specifications/)" values, which indicate primarily the amount of light lost to scatter.

The other important parameter is the spatial frequency of deviations from the desired curvature.  For a simple example, imagine some more-or-less parallel ridges left behind after a machining operation.  If the spacing is less than maybe 1/10 of a wavelength(for the range of wavelengths intended to be used), then they do not affect the optic's performance.  If the spacing is closer to a wavelength or so, then you'll get a diffraction grating effect.

For any surface, regardless of curvature (spherical, aspherical, planar), those are the primary types of non-smoothness that are used to evaluate surface quality.

Comment: Characterization by reference to wavelengths is decidedly not a geometric-optical approach, see the tags and title in the OP.

Comment: @Ruslan wavelength is most certainly part of geometric optics -- see "diffraction grating"

Answer (score -1):

In optic, a surface is smooth, if  it reflects light so, that you can see a picture behind the surface, if the image is only a little blurred you speak of an rathe smooth or generally smooth surface. It is NOT a mathematically defined smooth, which Slereah mentions, but of cause a mathematically smooth surface is also optical smooth

Comment: this is not correct.